# Empty ggplot when iterating over a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to iterate over a data frame and create a histogram and qq-plot for each variable in a data frame, like so:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(qqplotr)

for(i in names(flights)) {
  this_hist <- ggplot(flights, aes(x = i)) +
    geom_histogram(color = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue", binwidth = 0.5)
  this_qq <- ggplot(flights, aes(sample = i)) +
    stat_qq_line(color = "red", distribution = "norm") +
    stat_qq_point(color = "darkblue", distribution = 'norm')
}
```

When I now try to call `this_qq` I get an empty plot. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try `{{i}}` - but this still won't work as you want - only the last plot will be available

Answer (score 1):

Store plots in a list. Try :

```
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(qqplotr)
library(rlang)

this_hist <- vector('list', ncol(flights))
this_qq <- vector('list', ncol(flights))

for(i in seq_along(names(flights))) {
   this_hist[[i]] <- ggplot(flights, aes(x = !!sym(names(flights)[i]))) +
       geom_histogram(color = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue", binwidth = 0.5)
   this_qq[[i]] <- ggplot(flights, aes(sample = i)) +
            stat_qq_line(color = "red", distribution = "norm") +
            stat_qq_point(color = "darkblue", distribution = 'norm')
}
```

You can access individual plots with `this_hist[[1]]`, `this_qq[[1]]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`aes_string` can also be the answer (the problem here is that ggplot doesn't now how to interpret "i", you need to specify that i stores the string variable you want to plot) :

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(qqplotr)

for(i in names(flights)) {
  this_hist <- ggplot(flights, aes_string(x = i)) +
    geom_histogram(color = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue", binwidth = 0.5)
  this_qq <- ggplot(flights, aes_string(sample = i)) +
    stat_qq_line(color = "red", distribution = "norm") +
    stat_qq_point(color = "darkblue", distribution = 'norm')
}
```